# Can't trigger beforeDraw with Vue-Chartjs (or any other plugins)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, chart.js, vue-component, vue-chartjs

I'm trying to add custom text to the Chartjs chart (using vue-chartjs), what I've found out so far is that I need to do this via beforeDraw (or similar) plugin. I included the plugin in the options.plugins, but it doesn't get triggered.

What am I doing wrong? Here's the code

```js
<script>
import {Scatter} from "vue-chartjs";

export default {
    extends: Scatter,
    props: {
        chartdata: {
        type: Object,
        default: null
        },
        options: {
        type: Object,
        default: null
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        this.renderChart(this.chartdata, {
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            max: 100,
                            min: -100
                        },
                        type: 'linear',
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        type: 'linear',
                        ticks: {
                            max: 100,
                            min: -100
                        }
                    }]
                },
                elements: {
                    point: {
                        pointStyle: 'circle',
                        radius: 16,
                        backgroundColor: "#dc005a"
                    }
                },
                layout: {
                    padding: {
                        left: 25,
                        right: 25,
                        top: 25,
                        bottom: 25
                    }
                },
                plugins: [{
                        id: "AddLegend",
                        beforeDraw(chart) {
                            console.log(chart)
                        },
                }],
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Plugins can optionally be registered globally through [`Chart.plugins.register`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#global-plugins). You can register any of the hooks provided by the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) and provide your custom code. The `afterDraw` hook for example would have to be registered as follows:

```
Chart.plugins.register({
  afterDraw: chart => {
    // your code  
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I ended up adding the Plugin to the mounted() section as seen below:

Answer (score 2):

```
    mounted () {
    this.addPlugin({
        id: 'my-plugin',
        afterDraw: function (chart) {
            var ctx = chart.ctx;
            ctx.font = "bold 20px FiraGO";
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            ctx.textAlign = "center";
            ctx.fillText("ლიბერალური", chart.width/2, chart.height - 25);
            ctx.font = "bold 20px FiraGO";
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            ctx.textAlign = "center";
            ctx.fillText("ავტორიტარული", chart.width/2, 25);
            ctx.font = "bold 20px FiraGO";
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            ctx.textAlign = "center";
            ctx.rotate(Math.PI/2);
            ctx.fillText("გეგმიური ეკონომიკა", chart.width/(-2), 25);
            // ctx.save();
            ctx.fillText("თავისუფალი ეკონომიკა", chart.width/(-2), chart.height - 25);
            // ctx.save();
            // ctx.rotate(Math.PI/(-2))
            // ctx.save();
        }
    });
    this.renderChart(this.chartdata, {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        max: 100,
                        min: -100
                    },
                    type: 'linear',
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    type: 'linear',
                    ticks: {
                        max: 100,
                        min: -100
                    }
                }]
            },
            elements: {
                point: {
                    pointStyle: 'circle',
                    radius: 16,
                    backgroundColor: "#dc005a"
                }
            },
            layout: {
                padding: {
                    left: 50,
                    right: 50,
                    top: 50,
                    bottom: 50
                }
            },
    });
}
```